# Measuring the speed of an RPC client-server network

Tags: python, networking, rpc

The code below is a simple communication between a client and server network that determines if a message is an even or odd number. How do I measure the speed between the request and response ? I am not sure if my code measures it accurately.

```
import xmlrpclib 
import time  

start = time.time()
proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8000/")#manages communication with a remote XML-RPC server.
end = time.time()

#measures speed
elapsed = end - start
print "The elapse time is ", elapsed 

#the proxy variable connects to the server  and recives the result of whether the message is even or odd 
print "3 is even: %s" % str(proxy.is_even(3))
print "100 is even: %s" % str(proxy.is_even(100))


import xmlrpclib 
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer 

def is_even(n):  #determines if a number is even or odd
    return n % 2 == 0

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000)) # Creates server
print "Listening on port 8000..."
server.register_function(is_even, "is_even") # respond to XML-RPC requests
server.serve_forever()  #Handle one request at a time until shutdown.
```

Comment: Aren't you already meassuring the speed by "elapsed time"? What other sort of speed measurement do you need? You can do `start = time.time(); print("Took:", time.time()-start)` and that's the total time spent on the request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I put the output of the speed in a better string format?

Comment: Firstly, switch to Python3. Python2 is end of life in just a few months. Secondly, you can do `print(f"Total speed (in seconds): {time.time()-start}")`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to measure the time of the actual RPC.  Put your measurement around the `is_even` or `is_odd` call, not the `ServerProxy` construction.

You may also want to use a different clock.  `time.time` is the system wallclock time.  Instead, the POSIX_MONOTONIC clock will protect you from things like ntp clock skewing.

Comment: HI,can you please provide an example?Also what is ntp skewing ?